# append dynamic values to aria-labels in angular

Tags: angular, wai-aria

How to append two dynamic values to attr.arialabels based on certain condition

[attr.aria-label]="isSelected ? name + selected"

when the condition ,i want to append both the values and set the attr.

both are dynamic values.Any suggestions wil be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be

`[attr.aria-label] = isSelected ? name + "selected' : "not selected"`

Seems like more of a ternary javascript question.

Comment: you are correct ,it is a ternary operator .                                                                                                      [attr.aria-label] = isSelected ? name + selected : "not selected"                                   I want to append dynamic values     name and selected are dynamic values , not selected is also a dynamic value.

Comment: ok, so what's the question?  does the ternary operator not work?

Comment: ternary operator is working . The question is 'name' and 'selected' are dynamically values ,how to append the values?   If i want only name ,i can place using interpolation {{name}}  . Since the both are dynamic values , I am not sure how to append both and get the value in interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case both the below snippets works iff `client.issbInstalled` is true or false

```
[attr.aria-label]="((client.issbInstalled)? 'Secure Browser is installed' :
 'Secure Browser is not installed ') + 'with' + index + client?.clientHostName"
```

OR

```
[attr.aria-label]="{
 true:'Secure Browser is installed with' + client?.clientHostName, 
 false: 'Secure Browser is not installed with' + client?.clientHostName
}[client.issbInstalled]"
```